# Calculating a new column using two other columns by considering time decaying factor

Tags: sql-server, formula, calculated-columns

My question is a little tricky and I would appreciate if anyone help me.

I have the following table which I want to calculate the last column (intellectual capital prior to current competition) based on the scores users received in the previous competitions. the scores decays over time by  the following formula:

score*e^(-t/500)

t is the number of days that have passed from the prior competition. if the user have participated in more than one competition prior to the current one we add the scores.

the following table illustrates what I want to calculate.

```html
competitionsId  UserId date  score  intellectual-capital-prior-to-current 
1 100 1/1/2015 3000 
1 200 1/1/2015 3000 
1 300 1/1/2015 3000 
1 400 1/1/2015 3000 
2 100 1/5/2015 4000 3000* POWER(e, -4/500)
2 400 1/5/2015 4000 3000* POWER(e, -4/500)
3 100 1/10/2015 1200 3000* POWER(e,-9/500)+ 4000*POWER(e,-5/500)
3 300 1/10/2015 1200 3000*POWER(e,-9/500)
3 400 1/10/2015 1200 3000* POWER(e, -9/500) + 4000*POWER(e,-5/500)
4 200 1/20/2015 1000 3000*POWER(e,-19/500)
4 300 1/20/2015 1000 3000*POWER(e,-19/500)+ 1200*POWER(e,-10/500)
```

for example prior to competition 3, user100 has participated in competition 2 and competition 1. her score in competition 1 is 3000 so considering decaying factor we have 3000*e^(-9/500) and her score in competition 2 is 4000 so considering decaying factor we have 4000*e^(-5/500). Therefore user100 intellectual-capital in competition 3 is: 3000*e^(-9/500) + 4000*e^(-5/500)

Comment: what database are you using? "sql" does not tell us enough as each dbms platform uses different syntax for a range of operations.

Comment: @ Used_By_Already I use sql

Comment: "I use sql".... if you actually mean "I use sql-server" please note that Microsoft has no rights over the term "sql" . SQL is a standard, not a product. Use the tag "sql-server" instead.

Comment: @Used_By_Already Thanks for clarification. I edit my tangs and I'll use sql-server tag for my next questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following may help you arrive at the wanted calculation. I wasn't entirely sure what `e` represents in your formula, but with some window functions we can get the needed previous values and also accumulate values.

[**DEMO at SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/aa6086/2) (MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup)

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([competitionsId] int, [UserId] int, [date] datetime, [score] int, [note] varchar(45))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([competitionsId], [UserId], [date], [score], [note])
VALUES
    (1, 100, '2015-01-01 00:00:00', 3000, '-'),
    (1, 200, '2015-01-01 00:00:00', 3000, '-'),
    (1, 300, '2015-01-01 00:00:00', 3000, '-'),
    (1, 400, '2015-01-01 00:00:00', 3000, '-'),
    (2, 100, '2015-01-05 00:00:00', 4000, '3000* POWER(e, -4/500)'),
    (2, 400, '2015-01-05 00:00:00', 4000, '3000* POWER(e, -4/500)'),
    (3, 100, '2015-01-10 00:00:00', 1200, '3000* POWER(e,-9/500)+ 4000*POWER(e,-5/500)'),
    (3, 300, '2015-01-10 00:00:00', 1200, '3000*POWER(e,-9/500)'),
    (3, 400, '2015-01-10 00:00:00', 1200, '3000* POWER(e, -9/500) + 4000*POWER(e,-5/500)'),
    (4, 200, '2015-01-20 00:00:00', 1000, '3000*POWER(e,-19/500)'),
    (4, 300, '2015-01-20 00:00:00', 1000, '3000*POWER(e,-19/500)+ 1200*POWER(e,-10/500)')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
with Primo as (
      select
              *
            , datediff(day,lead([date],1) over(partition by userid order by [date]),[date]) day_diff
      from Table1
      )
, Secondo as (
      select
              *
           , lag(day_diff,1) over(partition by userid order by [date]) t
           , lag(score,1) over(partition by userid order by [date]) prev_score
      from primo
      )
 select
        power(prev_score*1.0,t/500.0) x
      , sum(power(prev_score*1.0,t/500.0)) over(partition by userid order by [date]) y
      , competitionsId,UserId,date,score,day_diff,t,prev_score,note 
from secondo
;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/aa6086/2/0)**:

```
|      x |      y | competitionsId | UserId |                 date | score | day_diff |      t | prev_score |                                          note |
|--------|--------|----------------|--------|----------------------|-------|----------|--------|------------|-----------------------------------------------|
| (null) | (null) |              1 |    100 | 2015-01-01T00:00:00Z |  3000 |       -4 | (null) |     (null) |                                             - |
|    0.9 |    0.9 |              2 |    100 | 2015-01-05T00:00:00Z |  4000 |       -5 |     -4 |       3000 |                        3000* POWER(e, -4/500) |
|    0.9 |    1.8 |              3 |    100 | 2015-01-10T00:00:00Z |  1200 |   (null) |     -5 |       4000 |   3000* POWER(e,-9/500)+ 4000*POWER(e,-5/500) |
| (null) | (null) |              1 |    200 | 2015-01-01T00:00:00Z |  3000 |      -19 | (null) |     (null) |                                             - |
|    0.7 |    0.7 |              4 |    200 | 2015-01-20T00:00:00Z |  1000 |   (null) |    -19 |       3000 |                         3000*POWER(e,-19/500) |
| (null) | (null) |              1 |    300 | 2015-01-01T00:00:00Z |  3000 |       -9 | (null) |     (null) |                                             - |
|    0.9 |    0.9 |              3 |    300 | 2015-01-10T00:00:00Z |  1200 |      -10 |     -9 |       3000 |                          3000*POWER(e,-9/500) |
|    0.9 |    1.8 |              4 |    300 | 2015-01-20T00:00:00Z |  1000 |   (null) |    -10 |       1200 |  3000*POWER(e,-19/500)+ 1200*POWER(e,-10/500) |
| (null) | (null) |              1 |    400 | 2015-01-01T00:00:00Z |  3000 |       -4 | (null) |     (null) |                                             - |
|    0.9 |    0.9 |              2 |    400 | 2015-01-05T00:00:00Z |  4000 |       -5 |     -4 |       3000 |                        3000* POWER(e, -4/500) |
|    0.9 |    1.8 |              3 |    400 | 2015-01-10T00:00:00Z |  1200 |   (null) |     -5 |       4000 | 3000* POWER(e, -9/500) + 4000*POWER(e,-5/500) |
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Used_By_Already . I appreciate your help. You're genius

Comment: I tried to run this query in sql server 2008. but I got the following errors: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 4
'lead' is not a recognized built-in function name.
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 10
'lag' is not a recognized built-in function name.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near 'order'.

Comment: mmmmmmmm if you are running older versions be very fussy about the choice of tags. This makes it quit a bit harder as you have to simulate the effect of lead by using row_number() and joins on rownumber offest by 1, plus you might not have running sum() either (don't recall exactly)

Comment: @ Used_By_Already  I'm installing sql server 2016 . I hope it runs in it.  If it does not I"ll ask you for more details. Thanks so much :)

Comment: v2016 does have all needed features

Comment: @ Used_By_Already 
I run the program in SQL server 2016. I just do not know how to write formula to calculate the last column. because I need to write formula that adds the value from previous row to the value I create from the current row.  Would you please help me with that?  considering that the value of e is approximately 2.71828

Comment: The table I provided here is just the example. I do not have the note column in my table so I need to create it. And I cannot write formula for each user (like you do) and substitute values of t  and prev_score  because I have more than 100,000 users.  I  appreciate your help.

Comment: The note column is irrelevant. It isn't used in any calculation. It just happened to be in your sample of data & was easier to keep it.

Comment: Do you know how I can calculate the values of note column? I need to create that column.  For example how to write the query that gets the a value from the previous row of prev_Score and  multiplies with the e^ (t from previous row + t from the current row)  and etc.?