# Add the values of score column for a specific user considering time decay factor

Tags: select, group-by, sum, sql-server-2016, row-number

I asked a question in the following link and one of the members helped me to solve most of it (to calculate column t and column pre_score). But I need to calculate one more column. I explained the details in the following link.

[Previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47373657/calculating-a-new-column-using-two-other-columns-by-considering-time-decaying-fa/47374101?noredirect=1#comment81722400_47374101)

In summary, how I can calculate the intellectual-capital column using column t and column pre_score? intellectual-capital column considers the pre-score from all previous competitions and then multiplies each pre-score by the e^(number of days that have passed from that competition/500). in this example for each user we have at most 2 previous competitions but in my dataset it may be even more than 200 competitions therefore I need to have query that considers all scores from competitions and the time that have passed from each competition.
-->  the value of e is approximately 2.71828

```html
competitionId UserId    t pre_score intelectual-capital
1                100   
2             100        -4  3000 3000* POWER (e, -4/500)
3                100        -5  4000 3000*POWER(e,-9/500) + 4000*POWER(e, -5/500)
1                200   
4             200        -19  3000 3000*POWER(e,-19/500)
1                300   
3             300        -9  3000 3000*POWER(e,-9/500)
4             300       -10  1200 3000*POWER(e,-19/500)+ 1200*POWER(e,-10/500) 
1             400   
2                400        -4 3000  3000* POWER(e, -4/500)
3                400        -5 4000 3000* POWER(e, -9/500) + 4000*POWER(e,-5/500)
```

Comment: explain what `POWER(e` means please. what is the `e`?

Comment: @Used_By_Already e is  a mathematical constant which approximately equals 2.71828. for example Power(e,2) = 2.71828*2.71828 =  7.39

Comment: I have a very basic knowledge  of SQL Server and the help you are giving me is very useful and I do not know how to thank you. Sorry if I am bothering you with too many questions but I need to get the right column to use it in my analysis.

Comment: That question ("what is e?") got lost in the prior question. With that missing value, and a small tweak in the formula, I believe it is now producing expected values.

Comment: @Used_By_Already You are right. I wrote too much comments and the important answer was lost in the middle of comments. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This result:

```
| prev_score | intellectual_capital | competitionsId | UserId |                 date | score | day_diff |      t | prev_score |
|------------|----------------------|----------------|--------|----------------------|-------|----------|--------|------------|
|     (null) |               (null) |              1 |    100 | 2015-01-01T00:00:00Z |  3000 |       -4 | (null) |     (null) |
|       3000 |              2976.09 |              2 |    100 | 2015-01-05T00:00:00Z |  4000 |       -5 |     -4 |       3000 |
|       4000 |              6936.29 |              3 |    100 | 2015-01-10T00:00:00Z |  1200 |   (null) |     -5 |       4000 |
|     (null) |               (null) |              1 |    200 | 2015-01-01T00:00:00Z |  3000 |      -19 | (null) |     (null) |
|       3000 |              2888.13 |              4 |    200 | 2015-01-20T00:00:00Z |  1000 |   (null) |    -19 |       3000 |
|     (null) |               (null) |              1 |    300 | 2015-01-01T00:00:00Z |  3000 |       -9 | (null) |     (null) |
|       3000 |              2946.48 |              3 |    300 | 2015-01-10T00:00:00Z |  1200 |      -10 |     -9 |       3000 |
|       1200 |              4122.72 |              4 |    300 | 2015-01-20T00:00:00Z |  1000 |   (null) |    -10 |       1200 |
|     (null) |               (null) |              1 |    400 | 2015-01-01T00:00:00Z |  3000 |       -4 | (null) |     (null) |
|       3000 |              2976.09 |              2 |    400 | 2015-01-05T00:00:00Z |  4000 |       -5 |     -4 |       3000 |
|       4000 |              6936.29 |              3 |    400 | 2015-01-10T00:00:00Z |  1200 |   (null) |     -5 |       4000 |
```

Produced by this query, which now contains `e`

```
with Primo as (
      select
              *
            , datediff(day,lead([date],1) over(partition by userid order by [date]),[date]) day_diff
      from Table1
      )
, Secondo as (
      select
              *
           , lag(day_diff,1) over(partition by userid order by [date]) t
           , lag(score,1) over(partition by userid order by [date]) prev_score
      from primo
      )
 select
        prev_score
      , sum(prev_score*power(2.71828,t/500.0)) over(partition by userid order by [date]) intellectual_capital
      , competitionsId,UserId,date,score,day_diff,t,prev_score
from secondo
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/aa6086/4)

Comment: Yeah. This is the result that I was expecting. I hope it works fine for all data set. I appreciate your help. And again I apologize for making confusion and not explaining well. Thank you :)

Comment: well the formula is scalable, so "it should" work, but if you expand on the size and complexity of your sample data at sqlfiddle you could do some testing. However sqlfiddle does limit the total size of the left hand text box to 8000 chars.

Comment: I'll test on my dataset and will let you know if I have question. Thanks for being so generous in solving users' problems.